# How to model non-linear regression

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

I am trying to learn how to modell data (x and y) that looks when plotted like this:

[image]

Can someone perhaps recommend any good literature or video series on how to do such task?

Comment: Please tell us what is your data: what are the x's and y's? What is the purpose of the regression model?

Comment: I have randomly generated my x and y values and the purpose of the regression model is to fit this data well. I want to model it like a linear model.

Comment: What do you need the model for?

Comment: This does *not* look like an easy problem (much harder than "fit a straight line to these data please", so we really need more context.  Are you most interested in the discontinuity around x=-15? In an general description/predictive model for the overall time series? in the peak at x=0? In the damped oscillations for x>0? These features will probably all need to be modeled separately ...

Comment: One approach is to choose a piecewise function, which can be written concisely as a single equation with an appropriate use of indicator functions.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code that generated this plot, or even just a table of the data somewhere (e.g. github) where we can access it to try different models on it.

Comment: The most interesting part of this is the apparent discontinuity around $x=-13$. Since this is a simulation, could you say something about that? Is it really a discontinuity?

Comment: Tempting to try a plot digitizer. Maybe either https://plotdigitizer.com/ or https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/ would work. Need to check their docs' to see how they work, but I think the gist is you pick a couple of known points and it calibrates from there.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a discontinuous response to discrete controls. The first regime ($R_1,$ I'll call it) is in $x\in[-20,-12.5],$ the second $R_2$ is $x\in(-12.5,-3.5],$ and the third $R_3$ is $x\in(-3.5,20].$

For $R_1,$ I would go for a decaying exponential. I would fit
$$y= a e^{bx},$$
or equivalently
$$\ln(y)= \tilde{a}+bx.$$
For $R_2,$ it again looks like a decaying exponential, so I would fit a similar function:
$$\ln(y)=\tilde{c}+dx.$$
Finally, in $R_3,$ it looks like a damped sinusoid, so I would do the non-linear fit
$$y=e^{gx}\,[h\cos(jx)+k\sin(jx)]. $$
It would help if you are able to determine $j$ from a peak-finding routine. It looks like the period is about $7,$ so you could try
$$j=\frac{7}{2\pi}.$$
It also looks much more like a $\cos$ than a $\sin:$ you might be able to get by without the $\sin$ term, which would turn your problem into a linear regression.